# Can't install nala in ubuntu 18.04. What's the matter?

Tags: apt, package-management, official-repositories, nala

I was trying to install it and no results of it. But I'm using `apt` to do it.

```
ninjmango@lenovothinkpadt400:~$ sudo apt install nala
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nala
ninjmango@lenovothinkpadt400:~$
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I see `nala` available for *jammy* (22.04) and later (eg. `nala | 0.11.1~bpo22.04.1 | jammy-backports/universe | source, all`).  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reaches the EOSS next month; five years after its initial launch in 2018-April.

Comment: The [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/n/nala/nala_0.11.1/changelog) lists the first "experimental" 0.1.0 release as Nov 2021

Comment: Ask the packaging system: `apt-cache search nala`

Comment: Since Ubuntu 18.04 loses support this April, you really need to think about upgrading. See https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

Comment: No,you're it's no longer supported with the hardware and maintenance for the window but I heard that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS itself is still supported at April 2028. But I'm not sure what day it's at?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* in April 2028, five years after initial release (read https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support) though yes parts of it are still supported if you *enable* ESM or use Ubuntu Pro, allowing you to get five additional years of support for specific packages (*those covered by ESM/PRO which isn't all architectures & all packages*). Ubuntu 18.04 LTS support ends on this site next month (EOSS)

Comment: Nala was previously available for Ubuntu 20.04, but support was dropped, since it was too hard to maintain. Also, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Nala isn't officially supported on Ubuntu earlier than version 22.04.

Nala is available in the [Universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=Nala&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) as a backport for Ubuntu 22.04, and as a "normal" release on Ubuntu 22.10 and newer.

It's also available in the [Volian Scar repository](https://gitlab.com/volian/nala/-/wikis/Installation). The installation Wiki page here clearly states:

> #### Ubuntu 18.04 / Debian Buster and older
>
> Unfortunately Nala will not work on these releases or older. 
> The python versions are too old, and they don't have the required packages. 
> Having said that you may be able to look further below and install from source. These distros will
> not be officially supported.

*Nala was previously available for Ubuntu 20.04 under the package name `nala-legacy`, but the developers have dropped providing binary packages for this branch, since it was too difficult to maintain.*

So the only option to get Nala working on older systems is to manually compile from source, and in addition fix all required Python dependencies (which may be a complicated task).

Comment: So I just upgrade my system to ubuntu 20.04  and then can I install nala in my system

Comment: Only 22.04 and up to be officially supported...